# My c++ function is not running and I am not able to decode it

Tags: c++, function

Hey guys I am new with c++. I have the following function in c++ but it always gives me an error by the "double overlap" function and I do not know why. Can somebody tell me, what I am doing wrong?

```
double overlap(vector<double> &R1, vector<double> &R2) {
    // overlap in the x dimension
    double xmin = max(R1[0], R2[0]);
    double xmax = min(R1[2], R2[2]);
    if (xmin >= xmax) return 0;

    // overlap in the y dimension
    double ymin = max(R1[1], R2[1]);
    double ymax = min(R1[3], R2[3]);
    if (ymin >= ymax) return 0;

    double overlap_area = (xmax-xmin)*(ymax-ymin)

    return overlap_area;
}

int main() {
    vector<int> R1;
    vector<int> R2;

    // Coordinates of the rectangles
    // with the .push_back() function we are adding the rectangles to our vector to give it to the algorithm.
    // x: x-coordinate, y: y-coordinate, w: weidth, h: height - (w,h: distance from left/botton to right/top side of the rectangle)
    int x1 = 0, y1 = 0, w1 = 6, h1 = 9;
    R1.push_back(x1);
    R1.push_back(y1);
    R1.push_back(w1);
    R1.push_back(h1);

    int x2 = 3, y2 = 4, w2 = 3, h2 = 3;
    R2.push_back(x2);
    R2.push_back(y2);
    R2.push_back(w2);
    R2.push_back(h2);



    cout << "Overlap = " << overlap(R1, R2) << endl;
}
```

Comment: What is the exact error you get?

Comment: You've forgotten a semicolon at the end of  `double overlap_area = (xmax-xmin)*(ymax-ymin)`

Comment: Umm why is the datatype int in main and double in function "overlap"?

Comment: @Moe can you send the min max code as well. Need to work on a new things

Answer (score 1):

You declare (along with the definition) as receiving two references to vectors of doubles.

```
double overlap(vector<double> &R1, vector<double> &R2)
{ /* ... */ }
```

You call with two vectors of int

```
vector<int> R1;
vector<int> R2;
/* ... */ overlap(R1, R2) /* ... */
```

If you read the error message closely, I bet it will tell you this.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `vector<double>` as parameters for your function `overlap`. But in your `main()`, you have declared two vectors of type int and passing them to the function which is giving you error.

Just declare your vectors as :

```
vector<double> R1;
vector<double> R2;
```

And add *double* values to them and your program would run fine.

**Note** : your program has an **minor sytax error** as well because you haven't specified semicolon after :

```
double overlap_area = (xmax-xmin)*(ymax-ymin)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 errors in your program:

1. The statement `double overlap_area = (xmax-xmin)*(ymax-ymin)` should be `double overlap_area = (xmax-xmin)*(ymax-ymin);`
2. You are passing an `std::vector<int>` and accepting it as a reference in the function as `std::vector<double>` which is rightly pointed out by the error

   In function 'int main()':
   43:43: error: invalid initialization of reference of type 'std::vector&' from expression of type 'std::vector'
   6:8: note: in passing argument 1 of 'double overlap(std::vector&, std::vector&)'

You need to change the `R1` and `R2` in your main to `double` type `vector`